# ehcache "maxBytesLocalHeap" not overflowing objects to disk

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am using the following `ehcache(2.9.0 version)` config for caching around 2 GB of data.
In this config `maxBytesLocalHeap` is not getting honored. Objects are not overflowing to disk. I tried to test the config by setting `maxBytesLocalHeap="1M"`.

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="c:\\cache" />
    <cache
        name="cache1" 
        maxBytesLocalHeap="1M"
        maxBytesLocalDisk="5G" 
        overflowToDisk="true" 
        diskPersistent="true" />
    <cache
        name="cache2" 
        maxBytesLocalHeap="1M"
        maxBytesLocalDisk="5G" 
        eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="true" 
        diskPersistent="true" 
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="1"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"/>

</ehcache>
```

I am getting the cache instance as follows :

```
CacheManager cm = CacheManager.newInstance();
    Cache cache = cm.getCache("cache1");
    Cache cacheTrade = cm.getCache("cache2");
```

Have i missed any config?

Comment: What's the problem you are having? All mappings should be written to disk with your config.

Comment: i can see all the instances(55000) and memory(7MB in heap) using java visual vm.